# How to track table changes in Prisma?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to track changes to a table in Prisma, with a Postgres database. For example, the status of a task, who changed it, what they changed it to/from, when it was changed, and require a user-provided note that explains why they made the change(s).

Here is an example schema:

```
model Task {
  id       String     @id @default(uuid())
  name     String
  statusId Int
  status   TaskStatus @relation(fields: [statusId], references: [id])
}

model TaskStatus {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  tasks Task[]
}
```

I could create a separate table for each model that I want to track, such as a `TaskHistory` model with a `createdAt` field that represents when the change took place and all of the same fields as the `Task` model that holds previous values. When a change is sent to the API, I would pull the current values from `Task`, create a `TaskHistory` record with the current (now previous) values, then make the updates to the actual record.

However, this would be a lot to maintain as the schema changes over time, and most likely come with issues that I haven't considered. Is there another way of tracking **who** changed **what** and **when** on a given table or even within the entire database?

If Prisma offers this natively, please let me know what it's called!

Comment: Temporal tables could be one of the solutions if you don't want to maintain Audit Logs. Some databases, like PostgreSQL, have built-in support for temporal tables. These tables automatically keep track of all changes made to them, including the old and new values, and when the change was made. You can then query this historical data directly from the table.

Comment: I will do some research on temporal tables, thank you. If you are familiar with Prisma, would you happen to know if this is something I would need to manage separately and keep in sync with my Prisma schema?

Comment: You would need to manage temporal tables separately. But If you decide to create a new table called Audit Logs then you can manage it through Prisma Schema.